# How to install the ksysguard daemon on a headless server?

Tags: opensuse

I'd like to remote-sense performance data (CPU & RAM usage etc.) of my OpenSuSE 15.5 based headless server from my workstation. As running `top` in a terminal window is not enough for my use case, I'd like to use `ksysguard` you can also run as a daemon. I found an unofficial `ksysguard` package for OpenSuSE 15.4 and tried to install it:

```bash
valen:~ # wget https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/plasmaregataos/15.4/x86_64/ksysguard5-5.22.0-lp154.317.12.x86_64.rpm
--2023-08-10 21:47:40--  https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/plasmaregataos/15.4/x86_64/ksysguard5-5.22.0-lp154.317.12.x86_64.rpm
[…]
ksysguard5-5.22.0-lp154.317 100%[=========================================>] 338.47K  --.-KB/s    in 0.06s   

2023-08-10 21:47:40 (5.43 MB/s) - »ksysguard5-5.22.0-lp154.317.12.x86_64.rpm« saved [346592/346592]

valen:~ # zypper install ksysguard5-5.22.0-lp154.317.12.x86_64.rpm
```

At this point I'm getting puzzled as `zypper` now tells me that it will install 400 (four hundred!) new packages `ksysguard` depends on, mostly Gtk / Atk, Qt, and DBus libs.

So: Is it really necessary to install so much stuff to make `ksysguard` run as a daemon on a headless server and leaving the graphical data representation to a `ksysguard` instance running on a client machine? Or is there an alternative package, which lacks the whole graphical frontend? I know that such a solution used to exist, but some 15 years ago.